# PayPal IPN Listener - SSL Certificate Handshake Failure

Tags: php, ssl, curl, paypal, https

Running PHP 5.3.28 and curl 7.30.0 (OpenSSL/0.9.8y & libssh2/1.4.2) on Windows Server 2008 R2 using IIS.

I'm creating a IPN listener for PayPal Instant Payment Notifications using their sandbox environment, but no matter what I do I get SSL certificate errors like:

> error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Here is my code (where `$fields` are the correct fields to `POST` back):

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
if ($result = curl_exec($ch)) {
    echo 'result = '.$result.'<br>';
} else {
    echo 'result = '.$result.'<br>';
    echo 'errno = '.curl_errno($ch).'<br>';
    echo 'error = '.curl_error($ch).'<br>';
}
curl_close($ch);
```

So, I understand that the PayPal server [requires TLS 1.2 and does not support SSL 2/3](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sandbox.paypal.com%2Fcgi-bin%2Fwebscr), but I can't seem to get my `POST` request to work. I've tried:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`

...and I get the same error. I've also tried:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, n);`

...which gets these results:

- [default] = `35 error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure`
- 0 CURL_SSLVERSION_DEFAULT = `35 error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure`
- 1 CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1 = `35 error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure`
- 2 CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv2 = `4 OpenSSL was built without SSLv2 support`
- 3 CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv3 = `35 error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure`
- 4 CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_0 = `35 error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure`
- 5 CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_1 = `35 error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure`
- 6 CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2 = `35 error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure`

I also read somewhere to try this:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '\cacert.pem');`

Where `cacert.pem` is downloaded from http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html and placed in the same directory as my script. This doesn't make any difference.

Is my code correct..?

How do I make this work..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this working now, here's how:

1. Verify the certificate
2. Upgrade to at least PHP 5.6.0 / OpenSSL 1.0.1
3. Save and reference `cacert.pem`

## 1. Verify the certificate

Use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);` to verify the certificate.

## 2. Upgrade to at least PHP 5.6.0 / OpenSSL 1.0.1

Upgrade to **at least PHP 5.6.0**, which seems to bring along with it **OpenSSL/1.0.1i**. I think at least OpenSSL version 1.0.1 is required to support TLS 1.2, which PayPal requires.

## 3. Save and reference `cacert.pem`

Save **cacert.pem** from http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html locally (in my case to `c:\cert`), then update the PHP ini that you're using to reference `cacert.pem` [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35059828/1003183). Using the ini file saves you having to use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '\cacert.pem');` in every call.