# Certificate CA bundle file: PEM - PHP/cURL - Local install..?

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I'm using Windows Server 2008 R2 (with IIS), PHP 5.6.0 and cURL 7.36.0 to test against PayPal's TLS test URL:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://tlstest.paypal.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6); // CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '\cacert.pem');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

When I use `CURLOPT_CAINFO` and `cacert.pem` from http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html it works and I get:

> PayPal_Connection_OK

When I don't use `CURLOPT_CAINFO` I get this error:

> SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

I've tried this:

1. mmc
2. File > Add/remove snap-in
3. Certificates (Local Computer)
4. Trusted Root Certification Authorities > Certificates
5. All tasks > Import
6. Select `cacert.pem`
7. Message: "The import was successful"

However this has made no difference, I still have to use `CURLOPT_CAINFO` for it to work.

Is there any way I can install all these root certificates on our Windows Server so that I don't have to use `CURLOPT_CAINFO` and `cacert.pem` with every call I make..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can leverage your php.ini to set the absolute path of where the cacert.pem is located.

The directive is `curl.cainfo`

Set it, or at least read its value and place your file at the right position.

See: 
http://php.net/manual/en/curl.configuration.php